# Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.11

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I would like to use Php 8.0 in my homestead but i run into this error when i open the site "Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.11"

In my composer.json :

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0"
```

Running `php --version` in homestead machine (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) gives this :

```
PHP 8.0.0rc1 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2020 14:16:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.0rc1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I've seen somewhere that there's a difference between web php version and CLI version, but i'm not sure if that's related.

Comment: so, you are using php 7.4.11 when you run `composer`... are you running composer inside homestead or outside ? You can still use `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: Run `which php` and then open the `composer` executable and check the top line. It should look like `#!/usr/bin/php` or something make sure the path matches the path you got from `which php`

Comment: Thank you guys, not sure which one really did it, apparently i was running old version of composer i updated it and then ran php8.0 /usr/local/bin/composer update and added php:"8.0" in homestead.yaml, so a little bit of everything but its working as intended!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your CLI and web version of PHP is same or not ??.

check your web version by `phpinfo();`, either both are same or not!!!

if not then in your `Homestead.yaml,` you can specify a PHP version of your site.

```
sites:
-
    map: mywebsite.test
    to: /home/vagrant/code/public
    php: "8.0"
```